# Untar file to in memory data structure

Tags: python, tar

I have .tar file which contains other tar files and some simple text files. Ideally I would like to read the entire tar file including the sub .tar files into an in memory data structure for further manipulation. I'm looking for the most efficient way to handle this. The following provides a list of the files in the first level of the tar, but I need to detect the sub .tar files and then untar them.

```
tar = tarfile.open("test.tar")
#print tar.getmembers()
#filenames = tar.getnames()
for file in tar:
    print (file.name)
```

I've tried using the `is_tarfile()` method to check but that seems to need a filename.

Comment: Why not just mmap the whole file?

Comment: `fo = mmap.mmap(tar.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
`tf = tarfile.open(mode='r:gz', fileobj=fo)
`print tf.getnames()` I tried this but I get `AttributeError: 'TarFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'

Answer (score 1):

To get you further, here's a recursive routine to unpack a tar into strings and try to unpack the string as a tar:

```
import tarfile

def unpack(filename, fileobj=None):
    tar = tarfile.open(filename, fileobj=fileobj)
    for file in tar.getmembers():
        print (file.name)
        contentfobj = tar.extractfile(file)
        try:
            unpack(None, fileobj=contentfobj)
        except tarfile.ReadError:
            # print ("not a tar")
            print (contentfobj.read())


unpack("test.tar")
```

`unpack` takes a filename first time, then a `fileobj` provided by `.extractfile()` on each of the members. The last print shows how you can get the contents of the file if it is not a tar.